# GET-response returns Object containing Array but just the Array inside is needed (using ngrx)

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm using ngrx and want to receive an Array of type "ReceivingObject". However, as shown below, the GET-response returns it as an Array inside an Object.

```
{
  "receivingObject":
  [
    {
      "type": "xxx",
      "value": "yyy",
      "identifer": "zzz"
    },
    {
      "type": "xxx2",
      "value": "yyy2",
      "identifer": "zzz2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I know this issue must have been solved already 1000 times but I can't find the solution with ngrx. In the end, Instead of having the Object containing the desired Array, I'd rather just have direct access to the Array of type ReceivingObject as shown in the GET-request (returning an Observable of ReceivingObject[]).

[image: Redux-Action-Success screenshot(instead of myIdentification it would be "receivingObject" of course)]

Does anyone know how to approach this?

Here is the rest of relevant code snippets:

```
//object
export interface ReceivingObject {
  type: string;
  value: string;
  identifier: string;
}

// service
fetchAll(): Observable<ReceivingObject[]> {
return this.http.get<ReceivingObject[]>(this.url).pipe(fetchDelay());
}

// actions
export const fetchAll = createAction('[Receiving Object] Fetch All Objects');
export const fetchAllSuccess = createAction(
  '[Receiving Object] Fetch All Objects Success',
  props<{ receivingObject: ReceivingObject[] }>()
);

// effects
@Injectable()
export class ReceivingObjectEffects {
  fetchAll$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(Actions.fetchAll),
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.service.fetchAll().pipe(
          map((receivingObject) => Actions.fetchAll({ receivingObject })),
          catchError(mapAsFailure(Actions.failure))
        );
      })
    )
  );


  // reducer
  export interface State extends EntityState<ReceivingObject> {
    loading: boolean;
    loaded: boolean;
  }

  const adapter = createEntityAdapter<ReceivingObject>();

  const initialState = adapter.getInitialState({
    loading: false,
    loaded: false,
  });

  export const reducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(Actions.fetchAllIdentifications, (state) => ({ ...state, loading: true })),
    on(Actions.fetchAllIdentificationsSuccess, (state, { receivingObject }) => {
      return adapter.setAll(receivingObject, {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        loaded: true,
      });
    })
  );
  export const { selectAll } = adapter.getSelectors();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the object definition

```
export const fetchAllSuccess = createAction(
  '[Receiving Object] Fetch All Objects Success',
  props<ReceivingObject[]>()
);

map((receivingObject) => Actions.fetchAll(receivingObject)),
```

Comment: When removing the object definition, I receive the following error:

TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3, '(type: "[Receiving Object] Fetch All Objects Success", config: ActionCreatorProps<ReceivingObject[]> & "action creator cannot return an array"): ActionCreator<...>', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'ActionCreatorProps<ReceivingObject[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionCreatorProps<ReceivingObject[]> & "action creator cannot return an array"'.